# How to check if SQLite 3 DB table has schema and if not merge it with new one?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, database-design

Say we had created simple db table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (email varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, pass varchar(100))
```

now we want to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS or merge with previous one` that would look like

```
users (email varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, name varchar(100))
```

so if table existed we want to remove pass column and add name column.

Is such thing possible via SQL commands and SQLite pragmas or how to do it using C SQLite api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As it turns out](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11), in SQLite you'd have to recreate the entire table if you want to drop a single column.  The example at the link provided is pretty good - you may want to tweak it to suit your needs, though.

Here's what I came up with.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users_1(email varchar(100) unique not null primary key, user varchar(100));
INSERT INTO users_1 SELECT email, '' FROM users;
DROP TABLE users;
CREATE TABLE users(email,user varchar(100));
INSERT INTO users SELECT email, user FROM users;
DROP TABLE users_1;
```

Comment: this is quite sad... Is there any way to make your solution scalable (to any ammount of new colums)?

Comment: Yes - add more columns to the temporary table, then do more statements in which you `SELECT ''` from them.  I haven't had to do this before in SQLite (my DB was designed before I had to actually drop tables), but hopefully this points you in the right direction.